# Generate ExtJS 6.5 web app: [ERR] javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter

Tags: java, extjs, java-9, extjs6, extjs6.5

I am using Java 9.0.4, Sencha ExtJS 6.5.3.6 trial, at directory Desktop, I run command

```
sencha -sdk /Users/donhuvy/Documents/Setup/Software\ development/ExtJS/ext-6.5.3  generate app --ext --modern accounting_vy ./vy_sencha
```

I see error

```
Sencha Cmd v6.5.3.6
[INF] Copying framework to /Users/donhuvy/Desktop/vy_sencha/ext
[ERR] javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter
```

[image]

How to fix it?

Comment: I try something like this https://github.com/http-kit/http-kit/issues/356#issuecomment-340307541 But I found `/Users/donhuvy/bin/Sencha/Cmd/6.5.3.6/sencha.cfg`, but I don't know how to add JVM arguments.

Comment: should be sencha -sdk /Users/donhuvy/Documents/Setup/Softwar/development/ExtJS/ext-6.5.3 generate app accounting_vy ./vy_sencha --modern

Comment: It not work. I release command `sencha -sdk /Users/donhuvy/Documents/Setup/Software\ development/ExtJS/ext-6.5.3 generate app accounting_vy accounting_vy`. Error is the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JAXB APIs (include class `javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter`) now belong to Java EE APIs, and it is not existing in Java SE 9.

Solution: Install JDK 8, set it is default.

Reference: http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/320

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled on this post and ran into this problem some time ago. Just in case someone needs it, the solution (for Cmd 6.5.3.6 at least) wasn't to set JDK 8 as the default. The solution is to go into the sencha file and uncomment `INSTALL4J_JAVA_HOME_OVERRIDE` and set it to the java 8 JDK like this:

```
INSTALL4J_JAVA_HOME_OVERRIDE=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk
```